# Is $fft^{-1}(fft(x)\times fft(y))$ integer?

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I have some troubles with the following question:

Let ($x_0, x_1, ..., x_{N-1}$) and ($y_0, y_1, ..., y_{N-1}$) be two sequences of integers from the set {$0,1,...,9$}. Let ($p_0, p_1, ..., p_{N-1}$) be the sequence defined by $p = fft^{-1}(fft(x)\times fft(y))$. Prove that all $p_i$ are integers and that $0 \leq p_i \leq 100N$.

I have tried to solve it using the definition of the fourier coefficients but I end up with a mess of products and sums... I hope you can help me. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem#Functions_of_discrete_variable_sequences.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I don't get it... How does this show that $p$ is an integer?

Comment: The discrete convolution of finite integer sequences is an integer sequence. See the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution.

Answer (score 0):

$ifft(X \times Y)=ifft(X) * ifft(Y)$ with * a convolutive product.
Consequently $p = x * x$ (considering $x$ is repeated such that x is period N ($x(i+N)=x(i)$).

So,
$p_i=\sum_{j=1}^N x_jx_{i-j} \leq \sum_{j=1}^N 9\times9 = N81$
And $p_i$ is a sum and product of integer so it is interger.